# Azure Management API - 429 Too many requests

Tags: azure, azure-management-api

I built a web app that does queries to the Azure Rest API and creates resources (WebApp, 2 MySQL Databases, Adds a Hostname, Add an SSL Cert...)

All this queries go to:
https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroup}/....

After a few queries, I get a "429 - Too many requests".

Which limit does the Management API have? My account is not in Free Trial.

Seems like I just can make around 10...

Thank you

Answer (score 6):

Found my way here via Google after running into the same problem. There are limits, but they aren't that low by default.

The following page describes all Azure subscription limits:
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/azure-subscription-service-limits

The relevant limits (in case the page is taken down):

```
Resource                            Default Limit   Maximum Limit
Resource Manager API Reads          15000 per hour  15000 per hour
Resource Manager API Writes         1200 per hour   1200 per hour
Resource Manager API request size   4194304 bytes   4194304 bytes
```

If you get this error with only 10 requests, you might want to contact Microsoft as there could be soft limits on your subscription.

Comment: New home for this information: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/management/request-limits-and-throttling (after 6 years this is still very relevant - especially if you are plugging in to the new Azure RM SDKs).