# Deleting Azure App Service Instance via API: Error 429 Too many requests. Please try again later

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I was wondering if anyone else experience this error.

Just trying to delete an instance from our App Service using Microsoft's API:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/appservice/web-apps/delete-instance-process?view=rest-appservice-2022-03-01&tryIt=true&source=docs#code-try-0

Getting the following JSON response:

```json
{
  "Code": "TooManyRequests",
  "Message": "Too many requests.  Please try again later.",
  "Target": null,
  "Details": [
    {
      "Message": "Too many requests.  Please try again later."
    },
    {
      "Code": "TooManyRequests"
    },
    {
      "ErrorEntity": {
        "Code": "TooManyRequests",
        "Message": "Too many requests.  Please try again later."
      }
    }
  ],
  "Innererror": null
}
```

Does anyone know if this feature even works?

Comment: What did you try? The first script in the link? No lock on the resource?

Comment: I tried the API that's in the description to delete an instance. No locks

Comment: The `Error 429 Too many requests` indicates the request exceeds the rate limit. Did you use the rest api together with other command? Try to restart the app service, after it's ok, try to use the rest api (not with other command) to delete the instance process.

Answer (score 1):

You are facing a Transient issue with the Rest API, Check what is the Retry value in your header according to this [**MS Q & A Forum**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1138873/receiving-toomanyrequest-with-message-too-many-req) and retry after the seconds value specified in the Retry header.

According to this **[MS Document1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/management/request-limits-and-throttling#subscription-and-tenant-limits)** and this **[SO Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33282321/azure-management-api-429-too-many-requests)** by Martijn Stolk, There are certain Subscription Limits on Resource manager Operations.

> When you reach the limit, you receive the HTTP status code **429 Too many requests**. The response includes a **Retry-After** value, which specifies the number of seconds your application should wait (or sleep) before sending the next request.

***Make sure you are using correct parameters in your Rest API call.***

I used the **`Try it`** option for the Azure Rest API and it worked.

1. I listed all the Processes running inside Azure Web App:-

[Web Apps- List Processes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/appservice/web-apps/list-processes?view=rest-appservice-2022-03-01&tryIt=true&source=docs#code-try-0)

Rest API:-

```http
GET https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/{name}/processes?api-version=2022-03-01
```

[image]

**Output:-**

[image]

2. I listed all the Instances to retrieve the Instance ID:-

[Web Apps - List Instance Identifiers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/appservice/web-apps/list-instance-identifiers?view=rest-appservice-2022-03-01#webappinstancestatuscollection)

Rest API:-

```http
GET https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/{name}/instances?api-version=2022-03-01
```

[image]

**Output:-**

[image]

3. Now, I called Delete Instance Rest API to delete the Process 5612 that was running:-

[Web Apps - Delete Instance Process](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/appservice/web-apps/delete-instance-process?view=rest-appservice-2022-03-01&tryIt=true&source=docs#code-try-0)

Rest API:-

```http
DELETE https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/{name}/instances/{instanceId}/processes/{processId}?api-version=2022-03-01
```

[image]

I ran the API received a 204 response and when I ran  The List Process API Again the process with ProcessId 5612 was not present as it was deleted successfully:-

[image]

When I ran Delete Instance Process API again it showed- **`{"Message":"Process with an Id of 5612 is not running."}:`**-

[image]